# join separate files with python

Tags: python

I want to join 100 differeant files into one.

Example of file with data:

example1.txt has in this format:

```
  something
  something 
  somehting
```

example2.txt has in this format:

```
 something
 something 
 somehting
```

and all the 100 files have the same format of data and also have a common name example1.....example100 which mean the example is the same and have a number.

```
from itertools import chain


 infiles = [open('{}_example.txt'.format(i+1), 'r') for i in xrange(113)]
 with open('example.txt', 'w') as fout:
      for lines in chain(*infiles):
            fout.write(lines)
```

I used this but the problem is the first line of the next file joined with the last of the previous file

Comment: I would use 'cat' or 'gawk', even on windows.

Comment: On *nix: `paste example*.txt > joined`. The `paste` tool also comes as a part of cygwin for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 100 files, better to just use an array of files:

```
infiles = [open('example{}.txt'.format(i+1), 'r') for i in xrange(100)]
with open('Join.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for lines in izip_longest(*infiles, fillvalue=''):
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in lines]
        print >> fout, separator.join(lines)
```

Comment: thank for your answer I have also file with name 1_example_in an it is the same the number only chage I tried infiles = [open('{}_example_in.txt'.format(i+1), 'r') for i in xrange(100)] but the file Join.txt doesn't contain anything.

Comment: @HelenFirstrofen: Change the last line to `print >> outf, separator.join(lines)`. You also might want to `close()` all the `infiles` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would open a new file as writable: join.txt, and then loop through the files you want with a range(1,100):

```
join = open('Join.txt','w')
for file in range(1,100):
  file = open('example'+file+'.txt','r')
  file = file.readlines()
  for line in file:
    join.write(line)
```

Comment: The OP wants the data from each line in each of the files concatenated together on the corresponding line of the output file.

Comment: I really don't get that from his question @martineau

Comment: Yeah, it's misleading. Look at the link she added to her question.